# Correct SELECT/JOIN for "has login user liked"

Tags: mysql

We're having the following tables:

```
User (id, name)
Item (id, title, text)
Like (id, itemId, userId)
```

The Like table stores a has-and-belongs-to-many relationship between Item and User.

What is the most efficient way to select a list from Item and see if the "logged in" user has "liked" that particular Item?

```
SELECT * FROM Item ORDER BY published DESC LIMIT 10
(+ check if each Item has been liked by known user id, e.g. '123')
```

**Is this done best with a sub-select, join or two individual queries?**

Comment: What indexes and/or foreign keys do you have set up? Also, what information do you have to begin with? I'm a little confused--are you trying to generate a list of X items the user likes, or do you have a set of items and you want to see which of those the user likes?

Answer (score 0):

Joining is more effective than subselect, database engines are well optimized for joining tables.

The query (I have changed the name of table 'like', because it is a keyword in SQL)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM User u 
JOIN Likes l ON u.id = l.userID
JOIN Item i ON l.itemid = i.id
WHERE i.title = 'item' AND u.name = 'user'
```

If the result is greater than 0, the user liked the item.

EDIT: 
If you want to display the 10 newest items, and see if the user liked them or no, you can use this query:

```
SELECT i.id, i.title, IF(l.userID IS NULL, 0, 1) AS Liked
FROM item i 
LEFT JOIN Likes l ON i.id = l.itemID AND l.userID = ?
ORDER BY i.published DESC LIMIT 10
```

It is important to use LEFT JOIN, otherwise you will not get the rows the user has not liked.

Comment: The intention is to fetch a list of say the 10 most recent items, and check if the known user id has liked the items.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward way ( if i have understood the question right ) is

```
select * from Like where itemId = ? and userId = ?;
```

Assuming you have the itemId you want to check and userId from the session.
It will be good to have a composite index on table Like and columns itemId,userId to have fast returning queries.

Comment: The intention is to fetch a list of say the 10 most recent items, and check if the known user id has liked the items.